# array_sum multidimensional arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array

php
array_sum multidimensional arrays
I want to get the sum of the letter of each array. Please take a look of my code

Array
(
/*-----------------help---------*/

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1
                [b] => 0
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [a] => 0
                [b] => 1
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 0
            )

    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1
                [b] => 0
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [a] => 0
                [b] => 1
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 0
            )

    )
```

)
Sum of each array
want a result like this
Please Help

```
     [0] => Array
            (
                [a] => 2
                [b] => 0
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 0
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [a] => 0
                [b] => 2
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 0
            )
```

**need help**

Comment: in which programming language ?

Comment: this looks like php; and the question is not clear. There is an array of arrays of letter to number mappings and some sum makes the same array with double nuber and otherwise same structure. What is the operation?

Comment: the question is not finish, I have error posting in stackoverflow. Please help after I done with the question

Comment: Can you help me now with my question?

Comment: @JoseAlvinRañola Sure..what problem ur facing this time ?

Comment: thanks for the respond, sorry about the first question I was new in stackoverflow. In array[0] and array[1] is student and inside the array have questioner array[0][1],array[0][1] and array[0][2] each.
I want the sum of letter of question in each student. Please Look at my code.

Comment: I hope you understand my question. I really need this. Not good in array.

Comment: @JoseAlvinRañola I pasted some code below ..try to use this.i think it will help you to understand it how to iterate loops in php

Answer (score 0):

Without any tag I am explaining in terms of `PHP` as this is what it looks to me from my intuition :)

Once I know your language support, i will surely edit my post.

```
<?php

$myarr = Array(
        0 => Array
            (
                'a' => 1,
                'b' => 0,
                'c' => 0,
                'd' => 0,
            ),
            1=> Array
            (
                'a' => 0,
                'b' => 1,
                'c' => 0,
                'd' => 0,
            ),

        2 => Array
            (
                'a' => 0,
                'b' => 0,
                'c' => 1,
                'd' => 0,
            ),

    );

foreach($myarr as &$qwe )
{
 foreach($qwe as $key => &$value)
{
if($value == 1 )
$value++;
}
}

print_r($myarr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 0
            [c] => 0
            [d] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 0
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 0
            [d] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 0
            [b] => 0
            [c] => 2
            [d] => 0
        )

)
```